# Can't texture paint after seperating model

Tags: texture-painting

This happens only when I seperate the model. It works when it is not seperated. The extra collection I made does not interfere.
[image]

[image][image: This is what was done to seperate the model.]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you mean, maybe share your file or at least a part of it? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: What I did to seperate the model was go to Modelling tab, then select all, the under the mesh options I selected the seperate by loose parts option.

Comment: I have uploaded the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have opened a texture and a texture mask in the paint brush, remove them (or at least remove the texture mask, it is currently completely black so it won't let you paint anything):

[image]

Also don't forget to plug the *Image Texture* node into the *Principled BSDF* in the *Shader Editor*.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the answer by @moonboots - you can only paint the texture on one object at a time. Since you separated the loose parts into individual objects, you can now only paint on the selected **active** object.

In your screenshot you can see that the gun slide is not the active object since it has a darker orange outline instead of the lighter orange / yellowish outline the active object usually has.

In the *Outliner* window to the right you can see one of the invisible objects object having a highlighted frame - this is the active object.

By the way, you cannot change the active object in *Texture Paint* mode, you have to switch to *Object Mode*.

[image: active object]

Comment: Thank You! It worked like magic! Sorry for asking such a dumb question though, for I am a noob.

Comment: @AbdulMoezYousaf But actually without moonboots' answer just changing the active object alone will not help.